# How to change the Data Layer for both image and ground truth images while doing augmentation for segmentation?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, image-segmentation, pycaffe

I am doing augmentation to do segmentation task with `caffe`. The `Python Layer` that I have written is raising an error. The layer definition is like this:

```
layer {
    name: 'myaug'
    type: 'Python'
    bottom: 'data'
    bottom: 'label'
    top: 'data'
    top: 'label'
    python_param {
        module: 'augLayer'
        layer: 'CompactData'
    }
}
```

this is the net drawing:
[net drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c244m.png)

The error seems to be related to `numpy`:

```
File "/home/usersc/caffe/python/caffe/pycaffe.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy as np
File "/home/usersc/anaconda2/envs/mycaffe/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/home/usersc/anaconda2/envs/mycaffe/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/home/usersc/anaconda2/envs/mycaffe/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/home/usersc/anaconda2/envs/mycaffe/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/home/usersc/anaconda2/envs/mycaffe/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import _internal  # for freeze programs
  File "/home/usersc/anaconda2/envs/mycaffe/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_internal.py", line 14, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "/home/usersc/anaconda2/envs/mycaffe/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: /home/usersc/anaconda2/envs/mycaffe/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so: undefined symbol: _PySlice_Unpack
```

I am not sure, I am thinking should I add a `MemoryData` layer to keep the augmented data for me as in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36986583/changing-the-input-data-layer-during-training-in-caffe#comment61534562_36986583) since both data and label images should be sent synchronously. Is it like that `Data Layer` memory should be cleared?

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem importing `numpy`: this has nothing to do with your code/layer, your code was not even run yet.
Make sure numpy is properly installed on your machine and that your `$PYTHONPATH` environment points to the right places.

Regarding memory: the way you defined your layer, it performs the augmentations ["in-place"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38549596/1714410), that  is, it changes `data` and `label` blobs instead of making copies of the augmented inputs. Make sure you are okay with this kind of behavior. Furthermore, I don't think you need a `"MemoryData"` layer to carry out your augmentations, the `"Python"` layer should be enough.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to import numpy separately, and it is working well in the environment. I do not want to be in-place, but the problem is that in normal flow (without augmentation) some other layers are using `data` and `label` blobs (and I do not know how to handle this) . What do you suggest? How should I send the augmented data into the Network?

Comment: @sc241 some of your layers expects original "data" while others expects augmented "data"? does not sound like a robust plan...

Comment: No actually, both augmented and original data should go to the same path of layers in the network. That is why I was thinking whether to use a `MemoryData` to keep augmented one and then copy (send) it to the `data` and `label` layers (as tops in  `MemoryData` layer)or  my thinking is not correct?